# Getting "NotADirectoryError" Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to test an image as a background using pygame. I have been trying to fix this issue for a few days, and now have resolved to StackOverflow

The line I have written to load the image:

```
back_ground = pygame.image.load(os.chdir(r"C:\Users\zayaa\Desktop\GameSprites\L9.png"))
```

I have used a directory but I get "NotADirectoryError [WinError 267]"

I have already attempted the following:

```
back_ground = pygame.image.load(os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\zayaa\\Desktop\\GameSprites\\L9.png"))
back_ground = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/zayaa/Desktop/GameSprites/L9.png")
back_ground = pygame.image.load("C://Users//zayaa//Desktop//GameSprites//L9.png")
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Thank you,

OP

Answer (score 1):

[`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os) changes the current working directory to path, but does not return anything.

<s>`back_ground = pygame.image.load(os.chdir(r"C:\Users\zayaa\Desktop\GameSprites\L9.png"))`</s>

```py
back_ground = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\zayaa\Desktop\GameSprites\L9.png")
```

However, you can change the working directory and then load the file:

```py
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\zayaa\Desktop\GameSprites")
back_ground = pygame.image.load("L9.png")
```

Comment: @zkwho The comment section is not intended to ask follow-up questions. If you have a new question [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). 1. `os.chdir` changes the current working directory. 2. `r` ist the prefix for a raw string literal (see [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)). This causes that the backslash doesn't start an escape sequence but is the backslash sign itself.

Comment: @Rabbid76 unfortunately, I am encountering the same problem again

Comment: @zkwho So there is only 1 possibility left: The directory "C:\Users\zayaa\Desktop\GameSprites" does not exist or don't have access rights to this directory. Try a different directory and see if the problem persists.